# iphone keyboard enlarges to cover much of screen

Tags: iphone

I have an app which has an html file on the screen with a textarea where the user enters data.  However, when the user presses in the box, the virtual keyboard and textbox and entire screen enlarges as if you used a three fingered tap.  I can pinch the screen to get things back to the normal view, but I don't want the user to have to do this.  I should mention that the same code works fine on an ipad.  here is relevant code:

```
<div id="newtext">
<p>Enter Your Text Into the Box</p>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="txtArea"></textarea>
</div>
```

The relevant css is:

```
#newtext {margin-top:300px;text-align:center;font-size:60px;padding:10px;margin- 
left:20px;margin-right:20px}
#txtArea {font-size:30px}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What I've figured out now is that what's expanding is the div #"nextext" which includes the p tag and the textbox.  Both the p text and textbox grow larger and extend off the screen.  Is there a way to stop that from happening?